# Constraint on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, check-constraints

Hi I have a Receipt table (Id, total, Issue Date, Status, Operator) and an Employee table (ID, Operator ID, ...).

I have to define the following constraint:

> An operator cannot have more than one active receipt (status) at the same time per day.

This is my constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Receipt
ADD CONSTRAINT uniquenessScontrinoAttivo
CHECK (NOT EXISTS (SELECT I.ID, S. Date, COUNT (S.Id) AS Count
FROM Receipt as S NATURAL JOIN Employee
WHERE S.Status = 'Active'
GROUP BY I.ID, S.Date
HAVING Count> 1));
```

The error given to me concerns the fact that a subquery cannot exist. This constraint I tried to insert it in the Receipt table by clicking on constraint and specifying in check all that written above.

Answer (score 2):

If I followed you correctly, you can use a partial unique index for this:

```
create unique index unique_active_receipt
on receipt (operator, date)
where status = 'active';
```

Comment: I am a university student and it is the first time that I program in sql. I don't know exactly what your code does. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: @Antonio: sure. This constraints says: for a given `(operator, date)` tuple, there can be only one record where `status = active`. You can read more about partial indexes in [the Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html).

Comment: if I didn't want to use an index?

Comment: @Antonio: in Postgres, a unique index is the way to do what you want. Otherwise, you will need to implement a database trigger, which is more complex and requires more code.